Psuedoinverse of product of two symmetric matrices
I have two matrices, $A$ and $B$. $A$ is a symmetric blockwise diagonal matrix that can be represented as:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} A_1 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \cdots & A_n\end{bmatrix}
$$
Where each $A_i$ is square and symmetric. Because of this form, the pseudoinverse of A is simply:
$$
A^+=\begin{bmatrix} A_1^+ & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \cdots & A_n^+\end{bmatrix}
$$
$B$ is a square symmetric matrix with the same dimensions as $A$. From these conditions, I would like to find an expression of $(AB)^+$ that utilises the explicit formula for $A^+$. I know that under some conditions $(AB)^+=B^+A^+$ but this is not the case in my situation. Is there anyway to simplify the pseudoinverse of this product?
